# GitHub action - npm run build - No build output

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to set up an action to run build on push to main. The action is triggered and the workflow runs and completes without errors, but the build folder/files that should be generated are not there.

The workflow looks like this:

```
name: Rollup

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: ls
```

And the build in package.json:

```
"build": "rollup -c",
```

The output filename(s) and directory are named in the rollup.config.js file, and it builds locally without a problem.

The workflow log shows it is running the rollup process and says the file(s) are output to the folder, but no folder or files.
`ls` after the build shows that the dist folder has been created, but when I return to the root of the repo it is no longer there.

[image]

Have checked read/write settings on the repo etc.

Any pointers?

Comment: How are you concluding there's no build output? Do you have any subsequent steps failing for the lack of it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for looking. I have added an update. It would appear there is some cleaning up being done in the latter stages of the flow. Do I need to include something to make the folder persist?

Comment: What exactly do you mean _"when I return to the root of the repo"_? From your screenshot we can see that after `ls` the build ends, so the whole runner and everything in it is going to get thrown away. If you want it to _do something_ with those files, you have to _write that_ in the workflow definition.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Forgive me - this is my first experience of creating a workflow action. I think I get what you are saying - they are being built but outside of the repo. My aim is for them to end up in the repo folder. How do I copy them from wherever they are to the repo itself?

Comment: How do you get files you create _locally_ into the repo itself? But I'd recommend keeping a separation between _source code_ and _build outputs_, I certainly wouldn't commit and push `dist/` back to the branch it was built from (GHA is smart enough not to trigger another build, but it's still not a good workflow).

Comment: The thinking was to upload the src files from local to dev branch, pull request to main, after review and on pull, for main to run the rollup process. You are saying the output should go be somewhere else - which I get. I have been looking at actions/upload-artifact - is that the way you would suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitHub Actions, each job in a workflow runs in its own fresh instance of a virtual environment, to share data between jobs within a workflow, you need to use [artifacts](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact).

```yaml
name: Rollup
... 

jobs:
  build:
  ...
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build --if-present

    #  Store the dist folder
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: app-build
        path: dist


  deploy:
    needs: [build]
    steps:
      #  Get the dist folder
      - name: Download build artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: app-build
      - run: ls dist
```

You can also use [cache](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows) to persist data. Both artifacts and cache are used to manage and transfer data, but they serve different purposes and have unique characteristics:

- Artifacts are primarily used for sharing data between jobs in a workflow and preserving data after a workflow has completed.
- Cache is intended to speed up workflows by reusing data from previous runs of the same workflow, especially for dependencies that don’t change often.

Comment: That's great. I have done this to get a artifact zip file which works fine, and understand the flow better now. Thanks. Good to know that this is the way it should be done.